# Hive results in csv

Tags: csv, hive

Please I try this code in **Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292**
And I have an error.

How can I output a query in a csv without create a table?

```
hive --e 'select * from product limit 10;' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > ~/output.csv;
```

> Error: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near
> 'hive' '' ''

Answer (score 0):

Try with **one hiphen** `-` instead of two `--`.

```
hive -e 'select * from product limit 10;' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > ~/output.csv;
```